# Overloading > operator to recognise nodes containing strings

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have written a templated function to find the maximum between two variables. It works fine when two strings are entered. I then have a class which creates "Nodes" that contain a string. I am attempting to write an overloader function within the class so that the > operator recognises these Nodes.

Here is my templated function and my Node class. The line following the forward slashes is throwing an error when trying to compile:

```
template<typename T>
T maximum(const T& a, const T& b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

class Node{
public:
    Node(const string& s = "Default"):
        data(s){

    }

    string get_data(){
        return this->data;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  vector<Node> &v){
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            os << v[i].get_data() << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        return os;
    }

    friend bool operator>(const Node& a, const Node& b){
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(a.get_data() > b.get_data()){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

private:
    string data;
    Node* next;
};
```

Why can't the > operator work on my get_data() function?

Comment: You are calling a non-const function on a const reference. Change the get_data function to `string get_data() const { return this->data; }`.  BTW post the error messages you are getting in future.

Comment: I knew it was a problem with the consts somewhere from the error message, but I didn't even think of the get_data function. I am new to C++ and find the compiler errors very difficult to make sense of. Thank you.

Comment: @KOB Also, the way C++ programmers do this is to overload `operator <` and `operator ==` and write the other operators in terms of these two.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wouldn't go that far...  it's quite fine to implement `operator>` this way

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my assignment states to do it the way you have mentioned. What is the reasoning behind this? To me it just seems like adding in extra unnecessary work.

Comment: @KOB The reason is that most container classes in C++ uses `operator <` by default to place items in order. Try to do `std::set<Node>` or `std::map<Node, int>` for example. And in any event, what's wrong with having `operator <`?  As a programmer, if I were to use your class, and I see `operator >`, I would expect it to also have `<, >=, <=, ==, !=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_data()` isn't a `const` member function, but the relevant `operator>` takes `const` references. Non-const member functions cannot be called via these references. You need to make `get_data()` a `const` member:

```
string get_data() const { ....
```

Also, use `std::max` instead of rolling out your own maximum function.